# Issue with Order By on Count of field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, sql-order-by

I have a table structure that looks like this:

```
ClassId
ClassDescription
```

My table's data looks like this:

```
ClassId  ClassDesc
4           --- 
4           ---  
4           ---
4
4
2
2
2
```

Now what I am trying to do is to get the count of `classId` based on each individual `classId` meaning, as an example, the above table would return a count of 5 for all of classId = 4 and a count of 3 for classId = 2.

So my Sql statement Count them individually and Order BY DESC On Count of ClassId
4 counts to 5
2 counts to 3

The final output should look like this:

```
ClassId       ClassDesc
    4           ----  
    2           ----
```

Comment: Is the `ClassDesc` always the same per `ClassId` or do you wish to concatenate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Group By

```
  SELECT classID, ClassDescription FROM  
     (SELECT classID, ClassDescription, COUNT(1) cnt FROM  mytable GROUP
      BY classID, ClassDescription) AS A
            ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

OR

```
   SELECT classID, ClassDescription FROM  <table> GROUP BY classID, ClassDescription
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Comment: Sir when we are counting the individual ClassId. After that if ClassId 4 Comes 5 times and And ClassId 2 3 times as 5 is greater than 3 So it should also perform Order By Desc and give Output

Comment: Sorry I didn't see order by before. I have changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ClassId, COUNT(ClassDesc) AS ClassDesc
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ClassId
ORDER BY COUNT(ClassDesc) DESC;
```

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ CLASSID ║ CLASSDESC ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║       4 ║         5 ║
║       2 ║         3 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21bc6/8)

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is your answer, you just need to put in some effort.

You want to try something like below:

```
declare @temp  table
(
classid int,
classdesc varchar(10)
)

insert into @temp
select 4, 'test'
union all
select 4, 'test1'
union all
select 4, 'test2'
union all
select 4, 'test 3'
union all
select 4, 'test 4'
union
select 2, 'test'
union
select 2, 'test 2'

select classid, count(*) classcount
from @temp
group by classid
order by classcount desc
```

I hope it helps!